# rdrop2 not working on EC2 server, but still working on localhost and shinyapps.io

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, shiny, shinyapps, rdrop2

I am making a shiny app that should download a .html file from dropbox and show it in said shiny app via a `htmlOutput()`. Furthermore, I have it running on a AWS EC2 t2.micro instance (with all the shiny server configurations based on [this article](https://www.charlesbordet.com/en/guide-shiny-aws/#%5D)). The problem is that my app works on localhost, shinyapps.io; but, it does not work on my EC2 instance. The app runs on Shiny Server (inside the EC2 instance).

Here is the source code (*app.R*):

```
library(shiny)
library(rdrop2)
library(httr)

# token <- drop_auth()
# saveRDS(token, "droptoken.rds")
# Upload droptoken to your server
# ******** WARNING ********
# Losing this file will give anyone 
# complete control of your Dropbox account
# You can then revoke the rdrop2 app from your
# dropbox account and start over.
# ******** WARNING ********
# read it back with readRDS
token <- readRDS("droptoken.rds")
# Then pass the token to each drop_ function
drop_acc(dtoken = token)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h1("rdrop2 practice"),
  htmlOutput("viewFile")
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  directoryPath <- paste0("path1/", "path2/")
  
  fileName <- "file.html"
  
  filePath <- paste0(directoryPath, fileName)

  # Download File
  filePut <-
    try({
      withProgress(message = "Generating File",
                   detail = "This may take few seconds depending of your Internet connection",
                   drop_download(path = filePath,
                                 local_path = "./www",
                                 overwrite = TRUE,
                                 dtoken = token)
      )
      
      fileName
    }, silent = TRUE)

  # Show File
  output$viewFile <- renderUI({
    
    validate(
      need(filePut, 'File Not Available')
    )
    
    tags$div(class="resp-container")
    
    tags$iframe(class="resp-iframe",
                seamless = "seamless",
                src = filePut)
  })
})


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When the app runs on localhost or shinyapps.io, the app does the proper thing and shows the html file on the `htmlOutput('viewFile')`. Meanwhile, it does not work on the EC2 instance. I searched all over the internet for some solution, but nothing I try works.

If somebody has some idea on what is causing this behavior, I will appreciate the help !

Note: I noticed that my EC2 instance does not send XHR requests during the app runtime (unlike in shinyapps.io)

### Expected Behaviour

My shiny app (using rdrop2) should find a .html file on my dropbox account, download it, and then be able to display it using `htmlOutput()`

### Actual Behaviour

The file is not found an it displays the error on the `try()` "File Not Available"

### Account Type

Dropbox Basic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happened to find a fix for my problem. It was all a matter of **chmod(ing)** the *www* folder. This way, the shiny user can have access to my *.html* files